# dropzone not working after deployment

Tags: postgresql, laravel, heroku

I have just deployed a website using Heroku and PostGres. I am able to upload to one form but not the others. Also works fine locally. Errors below:

> ## Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> 1/1 NotSupportedException in Driver.php line 16: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.
>
> in Driver.php line 16
>
> at Driver->__construct() in ImageManager.php line 108
>
> at ImageManager->createDriver() in ImageManager.php line 50
>
> at ImageManager->make('uploads/trucking/photos/1490198567-Screen Shot 2017-02-13 at 10.11.08 AM.png') in Facade.php line 217
>
> at Facade::__callStatic('make', *array*('uploads/trucking/photos/1490198567-Screen Shot 2017-02-13 at 10.11.08 AM.png')) in Photo.php line 68
>
> at Photo->makeThumbnail() in Photo.php line 61
>
> at Photo->move(*object*(UploadedFile)) in TruckingDeliveryController.php line 228
>
> at TruckingDeliveryController->makePhoto(*object*(UploadedFile)) in TruckingDeliveryController.php line 219
>
> at TruckingDeliveryController->addPhoto('11', *object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(TruckingDeliveryController), 'addPhoto'), *array*('id' => '11', *object*(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
>
> at Controller->callAction('addPhoto', *array*('id' => '11', *object*(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
>
> at ControllerDispatcher->call(*object*(TruckingDeliveryController), *object*(Route), 'addPhoto') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
>
> at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in Authenticate.php line 28
>
> at Authenticate->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(Authenticate), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
>
> at Pipeline->then(*object*(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
>
> at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(*object*(TruckingDeliveryController), *object*(Route), *object*(Request), 'addPhoto') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
>
> at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(*object*(Route), *object*(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\TruckingDeliveryController', 'addPhoto') in Route.php line 174
>
> at Route->runController(*object*(Request)) in Route.php line 140
>
> at Route->run(*object*(Request)) in Router.php line 724
>
> at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
>
> at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
>
> at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
>
> at StartSession->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(StartSession), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
>
> at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
>
> at EncryptCookies->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
>
> at Pipeline->then(*object*(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
>
> at Router->runRouteWithinStack(*object*(Route), *object*(Request)) in Router.php line 699
>
> at Router->dispatchToRoute(*object*(Request)) in Router.php line 675
>
> at Router->dispatch(*object*(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
>
> at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
>
> at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))
>
> at call_user_func_array(*array*(*object*(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), *array*(*object*(Request), *object*(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>
> at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(*object*(Request))
>
> at call_user_func(*object*(Closure), *object*(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
>
> at Pipeline->then(*object*(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
>
> at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(*object*(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
>
> at Kernel->handle(*object*(Request)) in index.php line 53

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing to do with dropzone at all. Your answer is clearly stated in the error. First line: `GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On heroku, you don't have the GD Library installed. This is not included by default (it appears - I don't use heroku).

*Ps: nothing to do with dropzone.*

In your composer.json add `"ext-gd": "*"`:

```
{
    "require": {
        ...
        "ext-gd": "*"
    }
}
```

Then re-build. Or push and recommit, etc. Or however it works on heroku. :)

Comment: After adding above line, then `composer update` AND THEN commit back to Heroku

Comment: Ok, so one of my uploads is working now after I re-updated composer and re-committed to Heroku. I have one other upload that is not working still.

Comment: The comment is too long to post but this is the beginning: 
<h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1> <h2 class="block_exception clear_fix"> <span class="exception_counter">2/2</span> <span class="exception_title"><abbr title="Illuminate\Database\QueryException">QueryException</abbr> in <a title="/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php line 729" ondblclick="var f=this.innerHTML;this.innerHTML=this.title;this.title=f;">Connection.php line 729</a>:</span> <span class="exception_message">SQLSTATE[42703]: &quot;pod_trucking_deliveries...

Comment: Just share the text...not HTML. That comment tells me nothing, but seems like you're running into a separate issue now.

Comment: Ps: don't forget to "accept answers" when you're looking for help (if they solve your problem). I noticed your past questions you never marked any as "accepted". This is a "no-no" on Stackoverflow - and probably explains why you're getting very little answers to your questions. ;)

Comment: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (10, uploads/trucking/pod/1490210580-LicenseCertificate-A480904.pdf, 1490210580-LicenseCertificate-A480904.pdf, 2017-03-22 19:23:00, 2017-03-22 19:23:00, null, null). (SQL: insert into "pod_trucking_deliveries" ("name", "path", "trucking_delivery_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (1490210580-LicenseCertificate-A480904.pdf, uploads/trucking/pod/1490210580-LicenseCertificate-A480904.pdf, 10, 2017-03-22 19:23:00, 2017-03-22 19:23:00) returning "id")

Comment: I added ID to my database and am still getting this error

Comment: Definitely a larger AND separate issue. Might be more suited as a new question on here. I'd try `composer dump-autoload` and/or `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Also, please accept this answer as "Accepted" if it fixed your initial issue. Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Comment: Post the link to your new question here. I think I might be able to help you. I just don't want to flood this thread ;)